# How to insert text to rich edit control in Win32 while preserving any previous formatting

Tags: c++

I'm developing chat application in win32. Currently i'm dynamically allocating memory for rich edit controls text, append new line and set the new text with SetWindowText.

When a message arrives with specific keywords the app colors the line and appends it to the chat window. Everything's fine. Problem arises when next message is received - any previous formatting is lost!

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you post the code that is not working? It's hard to tell what you might be doing wrong without seeing what you are doing.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/q1wbuY75 inserts text into the rich edit, but this part of code formats message when it arrives through socket http://pastebin.com/BKSNu7FF

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I've solved it. Apearantly I was replacing the text with unformated version of it. Here's how to properly append text to rich edit control:

```
CHARRANGE cr;
cr.cpMin = -1;
cr.cpMax = -1;

// hwnd = rich edit hwnd
SendMessage(hwnd, EM_EXSETSEL, 0, (LPARAM)&cr);
SendMessage(hwnd, EM_REPLACESEL, 0, (LPARAM)stringtoappend);
```