# How to insert text into my Rich Edit Control in VS2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc, richedit

I've already gone to this question:
[How to insert text to rich edit control in Win32 while preserving any previous formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267477/how-to-insert-text-to-rich-edit-control-in-win32-while-preserving-any-previous-f)

And I tried to do what he did, but I got met with the error that my SendMessage didn't take the same number of parameters.

And after looking at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t64sseb3(v=vs.100).aspx,
I figured that not all [SendMessage]s are created equal - that is that SendMessage in VS2010 doesn't take a hWnd parameter.

So... I'm stuck... Please help >_<

EDIT: I did do my research... I'm afraid I just was looking in the wrong places or do not know how to. I've been at this since yesterday...

Comment: All SendMessages are equal but some SendMessages are more equal than others

Comment: So how do i append text to a rich edit control in vs2010?

Comment: There are two methods called `SendMessage`: The Windows API interface in global namespace, and the MFC implementation part of `CWnd`. The latter doesn't need an explicit window handle. Without the exact error message, this question isn't really useful, tough.

Comment: This is just what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I learned today exactly how they were different.
Special thanks to IInspectable.

Scope.

The SendMessage that i was using was the MFC version which used 3 parameters.

```
SendMessage(message, wParam, lParam);
```

But I needed the one with 4 parameters - which was the WINAPI version.

..beat..

So that I'll be able to use the WINAPI one, i had to prepend my function call with the scope resolution operator (::). See below:

```
::SendMessage(rchWnd, EM_REPLACESEL, 0, (LPARAM)stringtoappend);
```

After that, I was happily able to append text to my Rich Edit Control (Yey!).
So... I hope that this question will help someone out there.

Peace... out ^^v

Comment: Why are you using `SendMessage` at all? Just call the method [`CRichEditCtrl::ReplaceSel()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zswk33at(v=vs.100).aspx), e. g. `m_richEdit.ReplaceSel(stringtoappend);`

Comment: Ugh... I can't believe that I'm only finding out about this... This does suit my purposes better... Thanks

Comment: On the other hand, would I not need send message if i'm accessing the dialog from the parent window?

Comment: The cleaner way would be to add a method to your dialog like `CMyDialog::AppendText(const CString& stringToAppend) { m_richEdit.ReplaceSel(stringToAppend); }`. Then you can call this method from the parent window.